# Extracting categorical cell values from raster to polygons- terra is dropping one of the polygons?

Tags: r, gis, raster, spatial, terra

I calculated several 'areas of influence' surrounding cities in Brazil, and created a shapefile which contains one area of influence per row.

This table is called 'kernels'.

| id | area | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alenquer | 1560201.2 | MULTIPOLYGON (7150563 680...) |
| almeirim | 14553177.7 | MULTIPOLYGON (7065229 681...) |
| alvaraes | 350435.3 | MULTIPOLYGON (6128735 674..) |
| curua | 22208870.8 | MULTIPOLYGON (7103585 675...) |
| fonte boa | 272623.4 | MULTIPOLYGON (6152826 669...) |
| manaus | 29844212.4 | MULTIPOLYGON (6535576 638...) |
| monte alegre | 8563165.8 | MULTIPOLYGON (7134992 679...) |
| obidos | 3051672.1 | MULTIPOLYGON (7123871 678...) |
| oriximina | 2147212.1 | MULTIPOLYGON (7118250 680...) |
| parintins | 8733992.4 | MULTIPOLYGON (6982311 673...) |
| prainha | 11036984.9 | MULTIPOLYGON (7230669 678...) |
| santarem | 1915913.9 | MULTIPOLYGON (7155300 680...) |
| tefe | 535865.7 | MULTIPOLYGON (6102565 675...) |

I also have a categorical raster of this area, with cell values corresponding to habitat types. This raster is called 'wetland_rast'.

I would like to get the area of each habitat type for each area of influence ('id').

```
    # rasterize for zonal calculations (drops Tefe)
    rast_zonal <- 
      terra::rasterize(terra::vect(kernels),
                       wetland_rast,
                       # for each row/municipality kernel
                       0:nrow(kernels))
                       # cover = TRUE)

    # make a combined raster for low habitats
    low_mun_raster <- c(rast_zonal,
                        wetland_rast)

    levels(low_mun_raster) <- NULL

    names(low_mun_raster) <- c("municipality", 'habitat_class')

    zones_low <- 
      terra::unique(low_mun_raster,
                    as.raster=TRUE)

    # calculate the area of each cell in wetland raster
    cell_area <-
      terra::cellSize(wetland_rast,
                      unit="km")

    # calculate area of habitats by municipality (zone)
    zonal_stats_low <- 
      terra::zonal(cell_area,
                   zones_low,
                   sum)

    # is this getting rid of municipalities with no wetland area?
    zonal_cats_low <-
      terra::cats(zones_low)[[1]]

    # merge dataframes
    low_hab_df <- 
      terra::merge(zonal_cats_low,
                   zonal_stats_low, 
                   by="label")[,3:5]

    # assign municipality values to raster
    low_hab_df$municipality <- kernels$id[low_hab_df$municipality]

    # merge habitat value with habitat class df
    low_hab_class_df <- 
      low_hab_df %>% 
      merge(habitat_classes_low,
            by.x = 'habitat_class',
            by.y = 'ID') %>% 
      dplyr::select(-habitat_class)

    # pivot so df shows habitat classes by mun id
    low_hab_pivot <- 
      low_hab_class_df %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = 'class_low',
                  values_from = 'area',
                  values_fn = sum) %>% 
      set_names(
        names(.) %>% 
          tolower() %>%
          str_replace_all(" ", "_"))
```

This works EXCEPT it keeps dropping my last row ('tefe'), so I cannot get the areas of habitat types for that id, but it does return an NA id. Also, it returns the municipalities out of order, which concerns me that something is getting mixed up along the way. See below for the output.

| id | habitat1 | habitat2 | habitat3 | habitat4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alenquer | 1.607301 | 40.0900252 | 6.720004 | 146.720092 |
| NA | 6.665964 | 1961.8912352 | 2.075631 | 5613.103534 |
| parintins | 1.784921 | 463.9202921 | 8.988606 | 1580.330995 |
| oriximina | 4.027773 | 1231.9207756 | 7.955905 | 2137.441346 |
| alvaraes | 9.840306 | 106.0900668 | 1.752001 | 599.960378 |
| curua | 2.941002 | 8.8700056 | 5.740004 | 4.330003 |
| prainha | 5.225523e | 1364.0708588 | 9.236606 | 1041.480656 |
| obidos | 4.145003 | 11.6600073 | 2.220001 | 35.470022 |
| fonte boa | 1.352576 | 4525.9928494 | 3.438562 | 6115.013850 |
| manaus | 5.300003 | 0.5700004 | 8.000005 | 1.810001 |
| santarem | 3.977703 | 139.8000880 | 1.999102 | 117.200074 |
| almeirim | 2.196001 | 2.9600019 | 2.010001 | 1.600001 |

I know for a fact some of these calculations are WAY off. Manaus should be much MUCH larger in all areas.

I get the error "Failed to compute min/max, no valid pixels found in sampling. (GDAL error 1)" for Tefe when I try to do it separately. This would suggest the area is too small, but that isn't the case for two other areas which are smaller than Tefe (i.e., Fonte Boa & Alvaraes)?

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: please edit your question, remove the tables, and instead provide a *small, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is, include code and data so that others can reproduce the problem. Create data with code, or use data that ships with R (see the examples in the help files)